# Where to place TCPClient script in Unity, and can I can implement scripts in the TCP code?

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, tcp, hololens

So I'm currently writing a C# TCPClient Script to work in Unity.

However, where do I put this script in Unity to make it work (more specifically to work for the Hololens)?

Also, can I implement methods from other scripts to function in the TCP Script as well? So for example, if the server sends the String "start", it will execute a "turn on" method from a timer script I wrote that starts the timer.

I'm still a bit new to network programming, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To make the TCP Client script work attach the script to an object in the scene and put the TCP Client initialization logic in the Start() function.

Making the Hololens work with your unity project will just require getting the hololens sdk and it wont matter how your tcp logic is implemented.

Unity will let you call methods from other scripts. For simple utility functions like the timer you mentioned I often make them static so that they can be called without creating a new instance of the class.